# Django templating in a meta tag in HTML?

Tags: html, django

I want to include profile.preferred_name in the meta tag below in the django template, but only if that data is present.

Essentially if the preferred name is present, show that, else, show the full name. How can I do this in a meta tag below?

HTML

```
 <meta name="More Info {{profile.full_name}} in {{profile.primary_office}}.">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <meta name="More Info {% if profile.preferred_name %} {{profile.preferred_name}} {% else %} {{profile.full_name }} {% endif %} in {{profile.primary_office}}.">
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`firstof`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext):

```
<meta name="More Info {% firstof profile.preferred_name profile.full_name %} in {{profile.primary_office}}.">
```